# WPF DoubleAnimation from CodeBehind

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-animation, doubleanimation

In the MainWindow.xaml I have this:

```
<view:CircularProgressBar Percentage="25"
                          ...
                          x:Name="speedoBar"/>
```

I had Percentage bound to a value I get from further outside. The problem is: it sets the value directly but I need to have a DoubleAnimation from where I am now to the value I just got.

In the part where I get the value I tried to create a new Storyboard and DoubleAnimation but nothing I try works.
I could think of creating a new DependencyProperty variable that will be DoubleAnimated and bind Percentage to it. But this value would be a double and I wasn't able to start a DoubleAnimation to a usual double-value. All I can find on the internet is a DoubleAnimation to an object's DpendencyProperty.

Then I tried to do the animation on the percentage value but the codebehind doesn't recognize it and VisualStudio suggests to create a new DependencyProperty-variable.

What I have so far is this:

```
// get the old value
speedCopy = speedoBar.Percentage;

DoubleAnimation speedDoubleAni =
new DoubleAnimation(speedCopy, (double)(vehicleDataViewModel.Speed), new Duration(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10)));

Storyboard.SetTargetName(speedDoubleAni, "speedoBar.Percentage");
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(speedDoubleAni, new PropertyPath(DoubleAnimation.ByProperty));

Storyboard story = new Storyboard();
story.Children.Add(speedDoubleAni);
story.Begin();
```

But it isn't working and shows the error at `story.Begin();` which means it's harder to find out the real problem D:

So how would you do that at all and what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You set `TargetName` and `TargetProperty` to wrong values. From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.storyboard%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

- `TargetName`: Gets or sets the **name of the object** to animate. The object must be a FrameworkElement, FrameworkContentElement, or Freezable.
- `TargetProperty`: Gets or sets the **property** that should be animated.

So in your case `TargetName` would be `speedoBar` and `TargetProperty` would be `Percentage` but you can set `Target` directly to `speedoBar` and, assuming that `CircularProgressBar.Percentage` is a `DependencyProperty`, below code should work:

```
Storyboard.SetTarget(speedDoubleAni, speedoBar);
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(speedDoubleAni, new PropertyPath("Percentage"));
```

Comment: I just refreshed to look for answers before I edit my post. I had the first line and SOMEHOW I didn't try to simply enter "Percentage". Still: Thanks. I feel dumb now, but you helped me a lot! :)